# Projecting over a find query with $elemMatch in mongoDB with the C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm trying to apply a projection using $elemMatch with the mongoDB C++ driver (2.6compat):

Sample document:

```
{ 
  "name" : "Tom",
  "lists" : [
             {"value" : 1}, {"value" : 2}, {"value" : 3}
            ]
}
```

I would like to get a document for Tom and ONLY value 1.

In the shell this will look like this:

```
> db.aaa.find({"name" : "Tom", "lists.value" : 1}, {"lists" : {$elemMatch : {"value" : 1} } })
```

Now, there's no suitable override over the `query` method which accepts a `BSONObj` for the projection part of  the query. Am I missing something here?

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you are going to want to use the DBClientBase::query() method. It has this signature:

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> DBClientBase::query(
    const string &ns,
    Query query,
    int nToReturn,
    int nToSkip,
    const BSONObj *fieldsToReturn,
    int queryOptions,
    int batchSize
)
```

In the 2.6 compatible C++ driver there are no database or collection classes so you need to provide:

- the namespace to query (ns)
- the query itself (query)
- the number of documents to return,
- the number to skip (pass zero for default values)
- the fieldsToReturn (a BSONObj representing the fields you would want back from the database.

So, for example, if you wanted to do the same thing as above you would write the query like this:

```
DBClientConnection conn;
conn.connect("localhost:27017");
BSONOBj projection = fromjson("{ lists: {\"$elemMatch:\": {value: 1} } }");
conn.query("db.aaa", Query("{}"), 0, 0, &projection)
```

Comment: Couldn't +1 your Solution, not enough reputation :) Anyway, it worked, except that the second argument should be a BSONObj, The "fromjson" part should be passed by reference, and you forgot to place values in queryOptions and batchSize.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to give you the gist of it. The last two arguments actually have defaults so you don't need them and query can be a Query object (which is easier to use). Thanks for the other feedback, I'll update it. (update: UPDATED)